# How to plot multi bar graph over time

Tags: pandas

I have data in the following format

```
+-------------+------------+
|    date     | ThisOrThat |
+-------------+------------+
| 2011-03-31  | this       |
| 2011-03-31  | that       |
| 2011-03-31  | this       |
| 2011-04-30  | this       |
| 2011-04-30  | that       |
| ...         | ...        |
| 2018-01-31  | this       |
| 2018-01-31  | that       |
+-------------+------------+
```

I need to plot a multi-bar chart over the months so it will show the distribution of "this" vs "that" counts.

this is an example of the format of the bar chart I need it in

[image]

I've tried to group the data by the date but I'm stuck on how to access and plot the value counts for the group

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.date,df.ThisorThat).plot(stacked=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Code below plots `count()` and `mean()` from sample dataframe.

**Import libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

**Create sample dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-01-23', '2018-01-23','2018-02-11', '2018-01-03','2018-02-01', '2018-04-04','2018-04-01',
                            '2018-02-26', '2018-02-21','2018-01-07', '2018-01-04','2018-02-28', '2018-04-03','2018-04-02',
                           ],
                   'ThisOrThat': ['this', 'this', 'that', 'that', 'this', 'this','this',
                                 'this', 'this', 'that', 'that', 'this', 'that','that',
                                 ],
                   'value': [212,333,433,232,454,232,56,454,676,454,677,454, 676,455]
                  })
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['month_yr'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%Y')) 
df.head(2)
```

[image]

**Plot count**

```
sns.countplot(x="month_yr", hue="ThisOrThat", data=df)
plt.xlabel('Month_Year')
plt.ylabel('Count')
```

[image]

**Plot mean values with error bars**

```
sns.barplot(x="month_yr", y="value", hue="ThisOrThat", data=df)
plt.xlabel('Month_Year')
plt.ylabel('Mean value')
```

[image]